# z3py: Is there a way to check configuration options in z3py?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

Suppose I define a solver in z3py as:

```
s = Then('qflia','skip').solver()
```

Is there way a to check the values of configuration options for s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`help`](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3py_1_1_tactic.html#a4447c2fba4e64dad4b7282b9d3bbd29d) function to get a list of parameters that the tactic is sensitive to, and if not set to anything else, they will have their default values. Note that tactics may change parameters internally, e.g., when the [`with`](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a0723a6e3eeca2a9198a5c982f500717d) tactic is used. Since tactics can override parameters multiple times, using different parameters at different points, there is in general not just a single value for a given parameter, and thus also no way to extract the current parameter settings.